# wp_mail in bluehost server the sender cannot be set

Tags: php, wordpress, email, shared-hosting

I have a function in my wordpress site, and its working.

```
function wp_send_email_shipping_confirmation( $args ){

    $content   =  send_email_shipped_confirmation( $args );
    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
    $headers[] = 'From: Wristband Creation Team <no-reply@' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . '>' . "\r\n";
    $mail = wp_mail( $args['email'], 'Your Wristbands Has Shipped Out', $content, $headers );

}
```

in my local server(mamp pro) i can receive it on gmail and the sender is no-reply@mydomain.com and that is working.

but when i uploaded it on my host(Bluehost) the email function is working fine aside from the sender it looks like this `(myhostID)@box421@bluehost.com`instead of `no-reply@mydomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

Hosting provider does not allow you to send email this way.

If you really want to send email from this account (`no-reply@mydomain.com`) you should create SMTP account in your domain and send mail through that using SMTP plugin, not wp-mail function.